# Prettier and Flask for Python in VS Code

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, prettier

I use VS Code and typically code in python and have been learning flask recently. This involves writing HTML etc. I have been using black to format my .py files and have been using Prettier for my other files. Is there a way to modify how prettier formats code blocks in HTML? For example, I find the following code rather unreadable, but this is how prettier is formatting it:

```html
<div>
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %} {%   if messages %} {% for category, message in messages %}
  <div>{{ category }}, {{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %}
</div>
```

I'd rather it looks something like this:

```html
<div>
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %} 
      {% for category, message in messages %}
        <div class="row">
          {{ category }}, {{ message }}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
</div>
```

Can I change settings or would you recommend a different formatter? Thanks and here are my setting for the workspace.

```html
{
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
  },
  "prettier.useTabs": true
}
```

Comment: _This involves writing HTML_ - what stops you from writing the HTML the way you want?

Comment: It looks has no method to achieve this for now. You can select the Prettier formatter for the Html and format the rest code blocks.

Comment: I have this same question, let me know if you find an answer to it.